# How to make a login page uses Single Sign On on WebSphere?

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, jaas

I have a web application deployed on WAS (8.5.5) where the login page was created using form login method, as described at: [Customizing web application login](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_pofolo.html)

I would like to use Single Sign On (Windows domain [Kerberos/SPNEGO]) on this web application login page, but have no idea of what I need to add to that code to make it use SSO.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by SSO.  SSO between different apps (then LTPA) , SSO with Windows domain login (then Kerberos/SPNEGO), something else you want to achieve...?

Comment: SSO with Windows domain login (Kerberos/SPNEGO).

Answer (score 0):

Just look in the documentation and other posts on SO regarding SPNEGO.
You dont have to do anything with your application nor login page. It is purely configuration on the server side. It is too broad to provide full configuration steps in this post.

Start with the following:

- [Creating a single sign-on for HTTP requests using SPNEGO Web authentication](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/tsec_SPNEGO_overview.html)
- [Implementing Kerberos in a WebSphere Application Server Environment Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247771.html?Open)

Comment: I don't think it's true (is not necessary to change anything) because I'm using a WAS that contains other projects. This server is configured with SSO and the other projects can enter without type user and pass but my project can't, it goes directly to the login page.

Comment: Just to make it more clear, if I open http://vmranisso:9080/ProcessPortal it goes directly to index.jsp without pass by login.jsp, if I open http://vmranisso:9080/TrainingProject it goes to login.html

Comment: @RanieriMazili Unfortunately you have to read a little bit, how it works and how it is configured from above links, before you make statements what is true and what is not.